# Как получить цену нефти?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю нефтяной кликер на юнити 
Мне нужно как-то получить стоимость барреля нефти
Находил в гугле способ,парсить xml.Ничего не понял
Может сможет кто-нибудь предложить варианты?

Comment: Ну так поймите. Вопросы "хочу сделать, но не хочу думать, так что напишите за меня" здесь не жалуют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю что такое нефтяной кликер, но чтобы получить цену есть несколько вариантов.

Два основных:

1. Найти сайт, где висит цена нефти и просто парсить html, например - [вот](https://www.finanz.ru/birzhevyye-tovary/neft-cena) или [вот](https://oilprice.com/)
2. Есть [API](https://www.oilpriceapi.com/), но там цена 10$ в месяц за 10000 запросов

Если нужно приближенное значение, то я бы в бд хранил цену нефти и обновлял ее раз в сутки. Можно даже кроном запускать скрипт не на c# (просто не знаю как там с парсерами и api), который будет парсить(делать запрос на апи) и обновлять цену в бд